# Angular - auth0 AuthHttpInterceptor not attaching token to requests

Tags: angular, authentication, flask, auth0

To cut a long story short, I am having problems with auth0's AuthHttpInterceptor class not actually attaching tokens to any outgoing requests.

I have been following [this tutorial series](https://auth0.com/blog/using-python-flask-and-angular-to-build-modern-web-apps-part-2/) in order to set up auth0 in a simple Flask and Angular application. I followed the Flask component, and have set up a simple endpoint to retrieve some data from my database. Note that the `@requires_auth` decorator is exactly the same as that in the tutorial:

```py
@app.route("/api/v1/members", methods=["GET"])
@requires_auth
def get_all_members():
    # Pagination Logic
    page_num, page_size = 1, 10
    if request.args.get('pn'):
        page_num = int(request.args.get('pn'))
    if request.args.get('ps'):
        page_size = int(request.args.get('ps'))
    page_start = (page_size * (page_num - 1))

    return_data = []
    for member in members.find().skip(page_start).limit(page_size):
        # Convert all IDs into strings
        member = convert_member_ids(member)
        return_data.append(member)
    return make_response(jsonify(return_data), 200)
```

This isn't the actual endpoint that will be restricted, I'm only protecting this page in order to test the auth actually works.

In Angular, this is consumed by a component which retrieves the data and displays it on the web page:

```js
export class MembersComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private webService: WebService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    if (sessionStorage['page']) {
      this.page = Number(sessionStorage['page']);
    }
    this.members_list = this.webService.getMembers(this.page);
    // TODO: Fix this with a proper expression
    this.num_pages = 90 / 10;
  }

  members_list: any = [];
  page: number = 1;
  num_pages: number = 0;
}
```

The resulting request is sent to `http://localhost:5000/api/v1/members?pn=1`.

I deviated from the guide and instead followed the [official auth0 documentation to implement an instance of the AuthHttpInterceptor class](https://auth0.github.io/auth0-angular/#call-an-api), and this is where the problems begin. My imports and providers arrays from app.module.ts are as follows:

```
  imports: [
    BrowserModule, HttpClientModule, RouterModule.forRoot(routes), ReactiveFormsModule, AuthModule.forRoot({
      domain: '<my app domain>',
      clientId: '<my client id>',

      // AuthHttpInterceptor
      httpInterceptor: {
        allowedList: [
          {
            uri: 'http://localhost:5000/api/v1/members?pn=1',
            httpMethod: HttpMethod.Get
          }
      ]}
    })
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AuthHttpInterceptor, multi: true
    }, 
    WebService
  ],
```

In theory, and according to the documentation, this should use the auth0 `AuthHttpInterceptor` class to intercept outgoing requests to attach authorization headers to them - in this case, only the members endpoint. Except, it doesn't. When I attempt to access the page, the outgoing request doesn't even have the header attached. This can be seen clearly in the console:

[image: Console log showing lack of auth header]

Since I have been following the tutorials and docs up to this point - what exactly am I doing wrong here? I have tried multiple different things and nothing solves it. Most of the other examples I have seen of this all implement it in a similar fashion, so I am confused as to why my code isn't working.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I've recently come across the same thing, and I wasn't setting the audience correctly in the interceptor.

Comment: I never found a solution to this, no. I'll give your fix and go and see if it helps.